# Initialize Spring Application Context for spring projects packaged as a jar

Tags: spring

We have several java projects.  Most of them are built with Struts 2.0 framework and few built with Spring 3.2.  We want to consolidate all the back-end integration service into a separate project using spring 3.2 and import this jar file on all the projects.  Here are my questions

1. What is the best way to initialize spring application-context for a jar based spring project?  This jar is utilized by multiple web-project that are built using Struts and other non spring MVC frameworks.

I read [How to package spring based library for reuse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116168/how-to-package-spring-based-library-for-reuse). However, this question didn't answer on how to auto-load the application context when you a call a Service from the built spring-example.jar file.

For example.  I have a WeatherService.java class in spring-framework.jar file.  I want to import the spring-framework.jar file into another Struts-MVC based application and call WeatherService.java from an Action Class.  I want the spring bean configuration to initiate automatically when calling the WeatherService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Import` annotation if using Java configurations or `<import>` tag if using XMl configs. With this approach you can reuse import one Spring context into another one.

Link to documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-using-import

**EDIT:**
If you are using maven, place your application-context.xml into src/main/resources. If not, make sure that it's on classpath.

Than if you are using XML config do

```
<import resource="classpath:application-config.xml"/>
```

or if you are using Java config do

```
@ImportResource("classpath:application-config.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My question is on how to call an imported framework-spring.jar file service from a struts based application without instantiating the bean configuration.  for e.g. I have a WeatherService embedded in spring-framework.jar file.  I want to import the spring-framework.jar file into an Struts-MVC application and call the WeatherService from an Action Class.  How to do it

Comment: Thanks Ikmac. Santosh