# NoClassDefFoundException loading an application jar file with spring application context

Tags: spring, jboss, java-8

I am getting an error when accessing the jar (rmi-proxy.jar) from my WAR file along with `ExceptionInitilizationError` during `JBoss` server startup, see below:

> 2017-10-11 16:31:47,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-10.73.132.41:15452-3) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [clientContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [clientContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I am currently working with EAP6.4, where the rmi-proxy jar I am using is built with Java6. The application working fine in one of the clustered JVMs (we are using clustering for `Jboss` servers with 4 JVMs), rest 3 not loading the application context xml.

Comment: There is no “`NoClassDefFoundException`” in your posted error. All I see, is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [clientContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: Hi, NoClassDeffoundException was also there when server start up which is invoking rmi-proxy jar and this is in turn causing filenotfound exception, but sorry I couldn't get the exact logs as its got overwritten

Comment: Sounds like confusing cause and effect. If these two things are related at all.

Comment: yes, I actually want to know how the spring application context should work in a clustered JVM environment bcoz I am currently doing the deployment in one JVM and the change should reflected in all others. But for this case, the context loading not happening In rest all JVMs.

Comment: I have seen exactly the same scenario which I am currently facing.                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236142/initialize-spring-application-context-for-spring-projects-packaged-as-a-jar   , but couldn't find the exact answer for this.